# Complex angular js ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have the component and have a problem setting the css class to it.
I want it to always have a class of "box", then to have additional classes specified by the directive "class" argument and one conditional class "mini".

Conceptually what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
<div class="box {{class}}" data-ng-class="{mini: !isMaximized}">
...
</div>
```

The problem is that when I set the class html attribute, the ng-class attribute is omitted. 
How to make my example work without changing the controller? Is it even possible, or should I set the class in the controller instead (which I wish to avoid)?

Comment: Looks like this is not an issue anymore with latest Angular.js version and the example above working out of the box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I needed multiple classes where one was $scope derived and others were literal classes. Thanks to the hint from Andre, below worked for me.

```
<h2 class="{{workStream.LatestBuildStatus}}" 
    ng-class="{'expandedIcon':workStream.isVisible,  'collapsedIcon':!workstream.isvisible}">{{workStream.Name}}</h2>
```

Comment: In newer versions of angular this actually works and is the best solution for the problem.

Answer (score 62):

A quick solution would be define the box class inside ng-class attribute:

```
<div data-ng-class="{mini: !isMaximized, box: true}"></div>
```

If you want to include a scope variable as a class, you can't use ng-class:

```
<div class="{{class}} box {{!isMaximized && 'mini' || ''}}">
```

Angular expressions do not support the ternary operator, but it can be emulated like this:

condition && (answer if true) || (answer if false)

Comment: What about assigning user specified attribute: {{class}} ?

Comment: revised my response to include a user specified class.

Comment: YOU, ARE, AWESOME! This saved me: "If you want to include a scope variable as a class, you can't use ng-class"

Comment: Also, AngularJS now has the ternary conditional operator.

Comment: @SiCK Please do not edit code, especially when your edit is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

*Edit: for newer versions of Angular see [Nitins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28731898/413785) as it is the best one atm*

For me, this worked (I'm working on AngularJS v1.2.14 at the moment so I guess 1.2.X+ should support this, not sure about the earlier versions):

```
<div class="box" data-ng-class="{ {{myScopedObj.classesToAdd}}: true, mini: !isMaximized }"></div>
```

I replaced your `{{class}}` with `{{myScopedObj.classesToAdd}}` to show that any scoped variable or even a bit more complex object can be used this way.

So, every DIV element crated this way will have "box" class and any class contained within `myScopedObj.classesToAdd` (useful when using ng-repeat and every element in the array needs to have a different class applied), and it will have the "mini" class if `!isMaximized`.

Comment: With this, I was able to do something like: `<div class="property" ng-repeat="property in properties" title="{{property.name}}" ng-class="{ 'property-{{$index}}': true, 'property-timestamp': property.name=='timestamp'}">`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this without double curly braces and includes scope variables, tested with angular v1.2+.

```
<div ng-class="['box', 
                aClass, 
               {true:'large': false: 'mini'}[isMaximized]]"></div>
```

It's also rather nice because the variable can use different types as a index without increasing complexity using ternaries. It can also remove any need for negations ;)
**[Here is a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13598/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple expression given below

```
ng-class="{'active' : itemCount, 'activemenu' : showCart}"
```