# Angular class expression in jade

Tags: angularjs, pug

Is there a way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607569/complex-angular-js-ng-class) in jade?
I've tried doing it several different ways but with no luck.
I also couldn't find anything similar to this.

I tried

```
.animated.{{class}}
```

but it compiled to

```
<div class="animated">.{{class}}
```

instead of (desired)

```
<div class="animated {{class}}">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do for you:

```
.animated(class='{{class}}')
```