# Angularjs ng-click-active class for anchor tags

Tags: css, angularjs

I have some styling I would like to apply when a link is clicked in my app.

If I was to use `ng-click`, then it would add a `ng-click-active` class to the element which is great, but is there a way to get the same behavior from an anchor tag?

Ideally if I had this markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#/item1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/item2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
```

---

I could style like this:

```
.menu a.ng-click-active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Why not use pseudo classes: `.menu a:active { background-color: #fff; }`?

Comment: You can do: ng-href="{{}}", or href ng-click=""

Comment: @Stewie of course!! was over thinking this...can you put as answer and I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a standard pseudo class to style the active state on anchor tags as well:

```css
.menu a.ng-click-active, 
.menu a:active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is kind of vague but in general you could use ng-class to conditionally apply classed to you elements
you could define a $scope property which defines when or when not to apply the ng-class to the element
example:

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="button" value="set" ng-click="myVar='my-class'">
  <input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
  <br>
  <span ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

you may as well see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607569/complex-angular-js-ng-class) post